How to select all text boxes in Microsoft Word?
How to select all text boxes so that I can e.g. change font for all, update fields for all?
Ctrl+A doesn't work.

Example: I opened a new word document, typed in "Hello" in the main space, and inserted a "Simple text box".
I then pressed Ctrl+A (Select all) and Ctrl+B (bold font). Only "Hello" becomes bold. Nothing happens to the text box. I want the text in the text box to also become bold.


Question unclear; is that e.g. in a document? Yes: Use Styles, change style font.

@Hannu: Please see edit. (And no I don't want to change Style because then any future text will also inherit whatever changes were made, which may not be what I want.)

Create a new document, save it as "template" (.dot file) - style changes in this one will not affect documents created with the default template.

@Hannu But I don't want future text in THIS document to change either

Well, apparently you see something that I don't understand.

As far as I know there is no way to do this. The best you can probably do is search the internet for a piece of VBA that selects each text box in turn (and that could mean each text box in the main body of the document, or every text box in the document), then modify it to do what you want each time you use it. (E.g. update all the field codes). For field codes, you can try using print preview to update them, but be warned: the widespread notion that print preview updates all field codes is incorrect.
